# I have 2 form on same page and i need the submit button to send the information to the right app.post in express.js, how do i do it?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post, express

Is it about the action=" " in the html form that makes the difference or the app.post("/..",...) that makes the difference?

```
app.post('/translate', function (req, res) { }
```

I have tried action="/translate" so it will be the same like in the app.post, but still it doesn't work.

here you can see mutual app.post but inside two actions, for form number1 and form number2 on same page.

```
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) { 

//for both forms
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({

    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'my_email@gmail.com',
        pass: 'my_password'
    }
});

//for form number1
var name1=req.body.name;
var email1=req.body.email;
var telephone1=req.body.phone;
var subject1=req.body.subject;
var message1=req.body.message;

  transporter.sendMail({
    from:  email1,
    to: 'my_email@gmail.com',
    subject: subject1 +"sender:"+name1,
    text:  message1 +"phone number:"+telephone1+"email:"+email1


});
}

//for form number 2 
var name2=req.body.Tname;
var email2=req.body.Temail;
var telephone2=req.body.Tphone;
  transporter.sendMail({
    from:  email2,
    to: 'my_email@gmail.com',
    subject:  "contact "+"sender:"+name2,
    text: "phone:"+telephone2+"email:"+email2  

});


 res.redirect('/');
 });
```

Comment: This is pretty vague, are they going to separate routes (the app.post bit) or to the same route? If they're going to the same one, use JS to collect all of the information and make a post request. If they're going to separate routes, make two ajax requests instead? Also, seeing as you're using post you need to put `method="POST"` in the top of your form, although that will still only send one form's data.

Comment: they both go to the same route but they use different actions that are written in the server.js.

Comment: I have added the code so you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make two separate [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) requests, send both sets of data with the same names (get rid of T**** and replace with just **** on the server side), then check to see if you've been sent the subject and body and do what you need to based upon that. This way you've got less code and it'll work.